# NoSQL data store, aren't we moving to the age of flat files?

Tags: database, nosql, ravendb

It's a hot topic in architect community "Moving to NoSQL DB". But my question is, Does NoSQL DB is capable enough to process huge database.

1. Does it support indexing
2. Does it support backups (data backup and log backup)
3. Is there Management Tools available
4. Does it support replication
5. Does it support Transaction

A developer can work independently on Relational Database. Does NoSQL has such tools. Can we use it in data center?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps have a google around first - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nirajan,
The answer to all of your questions with regards to RavenDB is that it absolutely does support all of those.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding RavenDB:

1. [yes](http://ravendb.net/documentation/how-indexes-work)
2. [yes](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-backup-restore)
3. yes (it's self-explanatory and missing from the documentation, but [it will be re-written](http://ayende.com/blog/99329/spiking-ravendb-management-studio-design-decisions) anyway)
4. [yes](http://ravendb.net/documentation/replication)
5. [yes](http://docs.ravendb.net/consumer/basic-operations/transaction-support.html)